# How member functions are implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, member-functions

I read somewhere that member functions are just like normal function in C++ but with an additional implicit `this` argument.

So I thought this program would be unable to distinguish between two `func`. But the program ran successfully. So was the statement stated above is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyCls {
    public:
    void func(int i) {
        std::cout << "Member" << i << std::endl;
    }
};

void func(MyCls m, int i) {
    std::cout << "Outside" << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MyCls m;
    // Thought both would have same signature void func(MyCls, int). But program compiled.
    m.func(4);
    func(m, 5);
    return 0;
```

Comment: The `func` inside the class has the full name `MyCls::func` so the functions have different identity. When you call a member function with an object as in `m.func()` the compiler knows that it should look for the function in the class of the object `m` rather than in the global name space. You may try to look up the concept of "name mangling".

Comment: You can see what @nielsen is talking about in action when you compile your code on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/7PWejh. The function definitions are separate in the generated code, showing one `MyCls::func(int)` and another `func(MyCls, int)`

Comment: The compiler implement m.func just like you implement func outside. The difference between your implement and the compiler do is the scope of member parameter. If the func outside want to access the member paramater will get a compiler wrong.

Comment: `void func(MyCls m, int i)` Note that there is a difference: you are passing the `m` argument _by value_, thus a copy of the original object will be made to be used in the function. If you want to pass a reference to the original object, use `void func(MyCls &m, int i)` or preferably `void func(MyCls const &m, int i)` if it's not being modified.

Comment: @JHBonarius You are right, but to mimic the signature of a non-const member function, the object should be passed by a pointer playing the role of the implicitly passed `this` pointer in the member function. E.g. `void func(MyCls *me, int i);`.

Comment: @nielsen yes, that is more true. And maybe for the future, we can use this as a sort-of member function with [deduced this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html)

Comment: @tentative is that all generated? Won't the `#include` append the entire iostream file to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this site](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/member-functions-cpp.php), just to pick a tutorial among others if you google the exact same question, you'll find this

> Member functions are the functions, which have their declaration inside the class definition and works on the data members of the class. The definition of member functions can be inside or outside the definition of class.

> If the member function is defined inside the class definition it can be defined directly, but if its defined outside the class, then we have to use the scope resolution :: operator along with class name alng with function name.

As you can see, a member function is a function which belongs to an instance of a class, having access to object's members and to pointer-to-self-object **this**

Of course, in your example you're accessing

```
m.func(4)
```

which is member function defined inside object instance of class `MyCls` whilst writing

```
func(m, 5);
```

you're passing an object instance of class MyCls to the function in the global scope (by value which is a thing you should study about as well if it's the way you want to act as) without using it, just to verify the coherence of your thoughts.

I suggest you to start with a good C++ tutorial to learn about the language's OOP paradigm.

Comment: Are you affiliated with StudyTonight?  If so, you must declare your affiliation.

Comment: of course not, i can change the link with any other website if it's a concern.
I just googled and picked the first one which defined in two lines what is the point of answer for the user.
I've just put the name out for site respect.

Comment: That's okay then.  That website is blacklisted by a script that combs Stack Overflow, so I don't know what harm there is in keeping it in your answer.  (sometimes machines get things wrong)

Comment: I couldn't imagine, I can look for an alternative. Is there a list in which i can look at websites blacklisted by SO? to get right the next time and to check for the next  link

Answer (score 0):

functions have different signatures, it can be seen inside list symbols of object file generated:

```
$ g++ -c my.cpp -o my.o
$ nm -s my.o

                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000000000c7 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z4func5MyClsi
0000000000000046 T main
000000000000007e t _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
0000000000000000 T _Z4func5MyClsi
0000000000000000 W _ZN5MyCls4funcEi
                 U _ZNSolsEi
                 U _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
0000000000000000 r _ZStL19piecewise_construct
0000000000000000 b _ZStL8__ioinit
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

so answering to your question, it is your second assumption which is wrong: sure, compilers always can distinguish normal functions from class members, by mechanism similar to namespaces (i guess).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It's unclear what you are trying to demonstrate by including the symbols of `my.o` in your answer. Can you please elaborate how this helps answer the question? I found the assembly output from Godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/7PWejh  much more readable as they show the different function signatures generated, for example.

Comment: well, Sourav Kannantha B asked about is it wrong that class member function are just like normal function with some specialties, and i decided to show intrinsic of compiler's output to demonstrate that it is not wrong - wrong was his assumption about compiler cannot distinguish between function and class member, and how.

Comment: Regarding "distinguish normal functions from class members, by mechanism similar to namespaces", so if we declare the function in the Class (member function in Class), will it be okay?

Comment: Please, share reason to use "s" symbol? (name mangling symbol: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html)